# Streaming recursive descent of a directory in Haskell

Tags: lazy-evaluation, directory-structure, haskell

I am trying to do a recursive descent of a directory structure using Haskell. I would like to only retrieve the child directories and files as needed (lazily).

I wrote the following code, but when I run it, the trace shows that all directories are visited before the first file:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad ( forM, forM_, liftM )
import Debug.Trace ( trace )
import System.Directory ( doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents )
import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import System.FilePath ( (</>) )

-- From Real World Haskell, p. 214
getRecursiveContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getRecursiveContents topPath = do
  names <- getDirectoryContents topPath
  let
    properNames =
      filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) $
      trace ("Processing " ++ topPath) names
  paths <- forM properNames $ \name -> do
    let path = topPath </> name
    isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if isDirectory
      then getRecursiveContents path
      else return [path]
  return (concat paths)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [path] <- getArgs
  files <- getRecursiveContents path
  forM_ files $ \file -> putStrLn $ "Found file " ++ file
```

How can I interleave the file processing with the descent? Is the problem that the `files <- getRecursiveContents path` action gets performed before the following `forM_` in `main`?

Comment: The later section called "Another way of looking at traversal" in the ["Searching the filesystem"](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html) chapter of Real World Haskell also provides a more flexible way of navigating the file system which uses a fold and an iterator.

Comment: I (obviously) took the function `getRecursiveContents` from RWH. I did not see the later section. I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out http://hackage.haskell.org/package/FilePather

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of problem that iteratees/coroutines were designed to solve.

You can easily do this with `pipes`.  The only change I made to your `getRecursiveContents` was to make it a `Producer` of `FilePath`s and to `respond` with the file name instead of returning it.  This lets downstream handle the file name immediately instead of waiting for `getRecursiveContents` complete.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad ( forM_, liftM )
import Control.Proxy
import System.Directory ( doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents )
import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import System.FilePath ( (</>) )

getRecursiveContents :: (Proxy p) => FilePath -> () -> Producer p FilePath IO ()
getRecursiveContents topPath () = runIdentityP $ do
  names <- lift $ getDirectoryContents topPath
  let properNames = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) names
  forM_ properNames $ \name -> do
    let path = topPath </> name
    isDirectory <- lift $ doesDirectoryExist path
    if isDirectory
      then getRecursiveContents path ()
      else respond path

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [path] <- getArgs
    runProxy $
            getRecursiveContents path
        >-> useD (\file -> putStrLn $ "Found file " ++ file)
```

This prints out each file immediately as it traverses the tree, and it does not require lazy `IO`.  It's also very easy to change what you do with the file names, since all you have to do is switch out the `useD` stage with your actual file handling logic.

To learn more about `pipes`, I highly recommend you read [Control.Proxy.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Comment: I updated the code for the current API of Pipes 4 instead of Pipes 3 but it's too long to paste here, so I gisted it: https://gist.github.com/FranklinChen/133cb61af931a08bbe20

Answer (score 7):

Using lazy IO / `unsafe...` is *not* a good way to go. Lazy IO causes [many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5892653/1333025), including unclosed resources and executing impure actions within pure code. (See also [The problem with lazy I/O](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Iteratee_I/O#The_problem_with_lazy_I.2FO) on Haskell Wiki.)

A safe way is to use some iteratee/enumerator library. (Replacing problematic lazy IO was the motivation for developing these concepts.) Your `getRecursiveContents` would become a source of data (AKA enumerator). And the data will be consumed by some iterator. (See also [Enumerator and iteratee](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Enumerator_and_iteratee) on Haskell wiki.)

There is [a tutorial on the *enumerator* library](http://www.mew.org/~kazu/proj/enumerator/) that just gives an example of traversing and filtering directory tree, implementing a simple *find* utility. It implements method

```
enumDir :: FilePath -> Enumerator FilePath IO b
```

which is basically just what you need. I believe you will find it interesting.

Also there is a nice article explaining iteratees in [The Monad Reader, Issue 16](https://themonadreader.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/issue-16/): *Iteratee: Teaching an Old Fold New Tricks* by John W. Lato, the author of the [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee-0.8.9.4) library.

Today many people prefer newer libraries such as [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes). You may be interested in a comparison: [What are the pros and cons of Enumerators vs. Conduits vs. Pipes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983840/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-enumerators-vs-conduits-vs-pipes).

Comment: I have added all of the references you gave to my Instapaper account and will read them after work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment by Niklas B., here is the solution that I have:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad ( forM, forM_, liftM )
import Debug.Trace ( trace )
import System.Directory ( doesDirectoryExist, getDirectoryContents )
import System.Environment ( getArgs )
import System.FilePath ( (</>) )
import System.IO.Unsafe ( unsafeInterleaveIO )

-- From Real World Haskell, p. 214
getRecursiveContents :: FilePath -> IO [FilePath]
getRecursiveContents topPath = do
  names <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ getDirectoryContents topPath
  let
    properNames =
      filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) $
      trace ("Processing " ++ topPath) names
  paths <- forM properNames $ \name -> do
    let path = topPath </> name
    isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist path
    if isDirectory
      then unsafeInterleaveIO $ getRecursiveContents path
      else return [path]
  return (concat paths)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  [path] <- getArgs
  files <- unsafeInterleaveIO $ getRecursiveContents path
  forM_ files $ \file -> putStrLn $ "Found file " ++ file
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I was recently looking at a very similar problem, where I'm trying to do a somewhat complicated search using the `IO` monad, stopping after I find the file I'm interested in.  While the solutions using libraries like Enumerator, Conduit, etc. seem to be the best you could do at the time those answers were posted, I just learned `IO` became an instance of `Alternative` in GHC's base library about a year ago, which opens up some new possibilities.  Here's the code I wrote to try it out:

```
import Control.Applicative (empty)
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Data.List (isSuffixOf)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, listDirectory)
import System.FilePath ((</>))

searchFiles :: (FilePath -> IO a) -> FilePath -> IO a
searchFiles f fp = do
    isDir <- doesDirectoryExist fp
    if isDir
        then do
            entries <- listDirectory fp
            asum $ map (searchFiles f . (fp </>)) entries
        else f fp

matchFile :: String -> FilePath -> IO ()
matchFile name fp
    | name `isSuffixOf` fp = putStrLn $ "Found " ++ fp
    | otherwise = empty
```

The `searchFiles` function does a depth-first search of a directory tree, stopping when it finds what you're looking for, as determined by the function passed as the first argument.  The `matchFile` function is just there to show how to construct a suitable function to use as the first argument for `searchFiles`; in real life you'd probably do something more complicated.

The interesting thing here is that now you can use `empty` to make an `IO` computation "give up" without returning a result, and you can chain computations together with `asum` (which is just `foldr (<|>) empty`) to keep trying computations until one of them succeeds.

I find it a little unnerving that the type signature of an `IO` action no longer reflects the fact that it may deliberately not produce a result, but it sure simplifies the code.  I was previously trying to use types like `IO (Maybe a)`, but doing so made it very hard to compose actions.

IMHO there's no longer much reason to use a type like `IO (Maybe a)`, but if you need to interface with code that uses a type like that, it's easy to convert between the two types.  To convert `IO a` to `IO (Maybe a)`, you can just use `Control.Applicative.optional`, and going the other way, you can use something like this:

```
maybeEmpty :: IO (Maybe a) -> IO a
maybeEmpty m = m >>= maybe empty pure
```