# What caused this "delayed read on closed handle" error?

Tags: haskell, ghc, lazy-io

I just installed GHC from the latest sources, and now my program gives me an error message about a "delayed read on closed handle". What does this mean?

Answer (score 13):

The fundamental lazy I/O primitive, `hGetContents`, produces a `String` lazily—it only reads from the handle as needed to produce the parts of the string your program actually demands. Once the handle has been closed, however, it is no longer possible to read from the handle, and if you try to inspect a part of the string that was not yet read, you will get this exception. For example, suppose you write

```
main = do
  most <- withFile "myfile" ReadMode
                (\h -> do
                         s <- hGetContents h
                         let (first12,rest) = splitAt 12 s
                         print first12
                         return rest)
  putStrLn most
```

GHC opens `myfile` and sets it up for lazy reading into the string we've bound to `s`. It *does not* actually begin reading from the file. Then it sets up a lazy computation to split the string after 12 characters. Then `print` forces that computation, and GHC reads in a chunk of `myfile` at least 12 characters long, and prints out the first twelve. It then *closes the file* when `withFile` completes, and attempts to print out the rest. If the file was longer than the chunk GHC buffered, you will get the delayed read exception once it reaches the end of the chunk.

#### How to avoid this problem

You need to be sure that you've actually read everything you need *before* closing the file or returning from `withFile`. If the function you pass to `withFile` just does some IO and returns a constant (such as `()`), you don't need to worry about this. If you need to it to produce a real value from a lazy read, you need to be sure to *force* that value sufficiently before returning. In the example above, you can force the string to "normal form" using a function or operator from the `Control.DeepSeq` module:

```
return $!! rest
```

This ensures that the rest of the string is actually read before `withFile` closes the file. The `$!!` approach also works perfectly well if what you return is some value calculated from the file contents, as long as it's an instance of the `NFData` class. In this case, and many others, it's even better to simply move the rest of the code for processing the file contents into the function passed to `withFile`, like this:

```
main = withFile "myfile" ReadMode
            (\h -> do
                     s <- hGetContents h
                     let (first12,rest) = splitAt 12 s
                     print first12
                     putStrLn rest)
```

Another function to consider, as an alternative, is `readFile`. `readFile` holds the file open until it has finished reading the file. You should only use `readFile`, however, if you know that you will actually demand the entire contents of the file—otherwise you could leak file descriptors.

#### History

According to the Haskell Report, once the handle is closed, the contents of the string become fixed.

In the past, GHC has simply ended the string at the end of whatever was buffered at the time the handle was closed. For example, if you had inspected the first 10 characters of the string before you closed the handle, and GHC had buffered an additional 634 characters, but not reached the end of the file, then you would get a normal string with 644 characters. This was a common source of confusion among new users and an occasional source of bugs in production code.

As of GHC 7.10.1, this behavior is changing. When you close a handle that you are reading from lazily, it now effectively puts an exception at the end of the buffer instead of the usual `:""`. So if you attempt to inspect the string beyond the point where the file was closed, you will get an error message.

Comment: why CW? you've made a valuable Q&A entry, get the rep you deserve! :)

Comment: @WillNess, it was more important to me, in this case, to get edits from other users, and upvotes to help people find this, than to get reputation for myself. I'm the one who pushed for this change in GHC, so it's my job to help people figure out what the new error means.